# What is "Almost" in Japanese

Tags: word-choice, usage

I have never actually seen the words for almost used in Japanese. Below are the various translations for "Almost" that I came accross:

> 「大方」
>
> 「粗」
>
> 「九分」
>
> 「殆」
>
> 「もう少しで」

Could you please highlight which should I use in those generic contexts? And also how to use them?

- I almost fell down
- I pray almost every day
- Almost all the gold is gone (to contrast with "Most of the gold is gone")

Comment: You know there's a corpus attached to most dictionaries that can give example sentences?  For instance, http://jisho.org/sentences?jap=%E4%B9%9D%E5%88%86&eng= and http://jisho.org/sentences?jap=%E6%AE%86&eng= (though for the second generally ほとんど in contemporary Japanese writing).

Comment: If you want to say "almost" as a single word statement, you could say "おしい". You can't use it as an adjective in a larger sentence. What was "almost" would have to be inferred by the context surrounding such a one word sentence. I think I've observed that, in a slang type of conversation, usage of "おしい" is not uncommon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no one particular Japanese word that you can use everytime you want to use "almost" in English contexts.

> "I almost fell down." = 「もう[少]{すこ}しで[転]{ころ}ぶところだった。」

That would be by far the most natural Japanese sentence.  Native speakers would almost never say 「ほとんど転んだ。」 unless they were trying to sound humorous. You, as a learner, could end up arriving at that if you tried to "directly translate" the English sentence "I almost fell down."

> "I pray almost every day." = 「ほとんど（or ほぼ）[毎日]{まいにち}お[祈]{いの}り（を）します。」

With this one (and the next one), you could use ほとんど/ほぼ like you would use "almost" in English.

> "Almost all the gold is gone." = 「ほとんど（or ほぼ）[全]{すべ}ての[金]{きん}がなくなってしまった（or simply なくなった）。」

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the relationship between `だけ` and `しか`, you could also use `[危]{あや}うく` or `[辛]{かろ}うじて` with the negation/opposite of what you are trying to say.  Since these words mean "barely", the negation/opposite of the premise would translate together as "almost".

例文:

> - 危うく終電に間にあった。　→　I ***barely caught*** the last train home.　→　implies "I ***almost missed*** the last train home".
> - 辛うじて試験に合格する　→　To ***barely pass*** the test　→　implies "to ***almost fail*** the test"

`危うく` can also carry the direct meaning of "almost", and be used similar to `もう少しで`.

> - 危うく[梯子]{はし・ご}から落ちるところだった。　→　I nearly fell off of the ladder.